# Fill the IList Collection using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq

Below is the Entity class

```
public partial class TestPlanViewModel
{
    public TestPlanViewModel()
    {
        this.TestPlanTestPoints = new List<TestPlanTestPoint>();
    }

    public int TestPlanId { get; set; }

    public string TestPlanName { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<TestPlanTestPoint> TestPlanTestPoints { get; set; }
}

public class TestPlanTestPoint
{
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }

    public int TestPlanId { get; set; }

    public string TestPlanName { get; set; }

    public int TestPlanVersion { get; set; }

    public int TestPointId { get; set; }

    public string TestPointName { get; set; }
}
```

I need to write a query where I need to get the collections from the `dbContext` like,

```
var query = (from tpm in TestPlanMaster
                         join tptp in TestPlanTestPoint on tpm.TestPlanId equals tptp.TestPlanId 
                         join tmm in TestMethodMaster on tptp.TestMethodId equals tmm.TestMethodId
                         join tpma in TestPointMaster on tptp.TestPointId equals tpma.TestPointId
                         select new
                         {
                             //Plan Details
                             tpm.TestPlanId,
                             tpm.TestPlanName,


                         }).ToList().Select(x => new Entities.CustomEntities.TestPlanViewModel ====> Custom Entity
                        {
                            TestPlanId = x.TestPlanId,
                            TestPlanName = x.TestPlanName,
                                                           TestPlanTestPoints = ?????? ==> how to fill this collection 
                        });
```

As shown above the `TestPlanTestPoints` is the `IList` collection object. I need to populate the data with the values from `TestPlanTestPoint` table.

Any suggestions?

Model
TestPlan

```
public partial class TestPlanMaster
    {  
        [DataMember]
        public int TestPlanId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public short TestPlanVersion { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int OrganizationId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public short TestPlanTypeId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string TestPlanName { get; set; }        
    }
```

TestPlanTestPointMapping Model

```
public partial class TestPlanTestPointMapping
    {

        [DataMember]
        public int OrganizationId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int TestPlanId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public short TestPlanVersion { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int TestPointId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This could be so much easier with AutoMapper. Use navigation properties in stead of joins and map entities to view models.

Comment: Can you give an example

Comment: Are those models coming from wcf service because of the DataMember attribute?

Comment: Maybe I can do more if you show your entity classes and the classes to which they should map. Currently, its very unclear which is which.

Comment: Yes but you don't consider this.
I just need a query wherein I need to populate the IList Collection object and return the entity as stated above

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking too much sql, think more linq. You want to select "tpm" items, so just write a select of those and select the new TestPlanViewModel and fill its properties and navigational properties.

I'm assuming you have a TestPlanTestPoints navigational property in your TestPlanMaster.

```
var q = (from tpm in TestPlanMaster
         select new TestPlanViewModel
         {
             TestPlanId = tpm.TestPlanId,
             TestPlanName = tpm.TestPlanName,
             TestPlanPoints = TestPlanTestPoint.Where(pr => tpm.TestPlanId == pr.TestPlanId).Select(tptp => new TestPlanTestPoint()
             {
                 // Fill properties here
             }             
         }).ToList();
```

Comment: How you refered tpm.TestPlanTestPOint ?
TestPlanMaster table don't have any Column TestPlanTestPoint

Comment: Edited my answer about the navigational property, the navigational property is called TestPlanTestPoints or should be if its pluralized, if its not its TestPlanTestPoint.

Comment: This is not a mapping table created by EF instead this is a separate entity (TestPlanTestPointMapping)

Comment: Please post information about your model then too if you want answer related to the question and not the viewmodels.

Comment: Edited the Question to include the Model Details

Comment: Edited my answer since you seem to not have the dbcontext available.